# Modeling a to-many relationship Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have two entites: `Folder` and `Picture`. A `Folder` can have many `Pictures`, and a `Picture` can belong to many `Folders`. However, there is one `Folder` called `All`, which holds all `pictures` belonging to any `folder`. So the `Folder` entity has a to-many relationship with `Picture`, so that each `Folder` has an `NSSet` of `Pictures`, and also each `Picture` has an `NSSet` of `Folders`. The `All` `Folder` contains all `Pictures`, but I don't want any `Picture` to have the `All` `Folder` as one of their `Folders`.

Currently with the way my model is set up, if I add a `Picture` to the `All Folder`, the `All Folder` is automatically added to the `Picture NSSet` of `Folders`, which I don't want. I think this happens because I have the two relationships as inverses of each other. But if I don't select the inverse option, my Picture entities begin only supporting one `Folder` instead of many.

The question is: how can I model my entities so that A `Folder` can have many `Pictures`, and `Pictures` can have many `Folders`, but if I add a `Picture` to a `Folder`, it shouldn't necessarily mean that that `Folder` is added to the `Picture`.

Here's my current model:

```
Picture: 
Relationship: Folder
Destination: Folder
Inverse: Picture
Plural: To-Many Relationship

Folder:
Relationship: Picture
Destination: Picture
Inverse: Folder
Plural: To-Many Relationship
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need an All folder at all? Is "All" its own entity, or is it a Folder entity with some sort of All identifier?

Either way, if you all you want is to grab all the pictures in any folder, you can do that pretty simply with a fetch request. No need to muck up your object graph with an extra entity or relationship.

Comment: No all is not an extra entity, its just a Folder object called All

Comment: Then why can't you just fetch all of your pictures? If you did a fetch for all pictures, that would give you all pictures for any folder. You can refine your fecthes for all pictures in a particular folder or folders, as well.

Comment: So that I can easily know how many unique Picture objects there are. Is there a way to find out how many Picture entities I have total at any given time, and have this number automatically update when Pictures are added or removed?

Comment: Your fetch request returns an array. Just count the objects.

Comment: But how can I do it without fetching? Fetching can be expensive, and if all I want is the number of objects of a certain entity, maybe there's a better way to do it?

Comment: How do you think you would get that entity to get the "count" property? Fetching.